# NUXT 3 [nuxt] [request error] File is not defined

Tags: nuxtjs3

I just have basic nuxt3 starter code but it doesnt work due to cryptic error.

How do I troubleshoot this error? Nuxt troubleshooting is really hard with no relevant messages and no stack trace for the code I wrote.

```
ℹ Vite client warmed up in 2929ms                                     10:20:14
ℹ Vite server warmed up in 1633ms                                     10:20:15
✔ Vite server built in 4061ms                                         10:20:17
✔ Nitro built in 336 ms                                         nitro 10:20:17
[nuxt] [request error] File is not defined
  at $id_a2da3f49 (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:18735:20)
  at async __instantiateModule__ (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:26247:3)
```

nuxt.config

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
buildModules: ['@pinia/nuxt'],
css: ['assets/css/main'],
})
```

assets/css/

```
@import "tailwind/_base.css";
@import "tailwind/_components.css";
@import "tailwind/_utilities.css";

@import "_checkbox-radio-switch.css";

@import "_app.css";
@import "_scrollbars.css";
@import "_progress.css";
@import "_table.css";
```

```
Layouts -> default.vue
<template>
  <div>
  <side-menu/>  
  <slot />
  <footer-bar />
  </div>
</template>
```

```
Pages -> index.vue
```

Comment: Hi, helping you debugging this one is already quite hard without more context. Please provide some code or a [repro].

Comment: added more context

Comment: Any luck on solving this?

Comment: i had the same error it was because using useRuntimeCOnfig() directly in var instead of affecting it like const runtimeConfig= useRuntimeConfig()